# How do I use the "Requires Moderator attention" option?

Tags: flags, support

How do I use the "Requires Moderator attention" option (when 
flagging a question)?

As far as I can see there only a 
Cancel button. I don't know how to send off the text for the "Requires Moderator attention" option.

**Update 1**: this happens if there are less than 10 characters or more than 150 characters - the number of characters must be in [10;150].

For the two other options, "Spam" and "Offensive, Abusive, 
or Hate Speech", there is a "Flag Post" button.

Don't I have enough reputation to do that? The FAQ only 
mentions one limit concerning flagging: "15   Flag 
offensive" and I currently have 201.

In particular I was trying to flag 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the option a text box should appear. When you've entered 10 or more characters into the text box explaining why you're flagging the post the "Flag Post" link should appear.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the reason: I pasted more than the maximum of 150 characters into the field.