# Flag Bug: "Flag Post" button for moderator attention is missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

There's no way to actually submit the flag for moderator attention. My rep is high enough on SO; the "Flag Post" button appears on the other two kinds of flags. I did start typing an explanation but the button didn't appear even after several words.

(Please disregard the fact that the question was closed by the time I was finished messing about with this.)

Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313535/anyone-have-access-to-the-monotouch-sdk-closed).

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10259/how-do-i-use-the-requires-moderator-attention-option/10260

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have at least 10 characters before <kbd>Flag Post</kbd> becomes visible.

If you don't explain why you are flagging it, how will the moderators know why you are flagging it?

If you don't use at least 10 characters, your explanation would probably be very cryptic.

---

I think it should remain visible, but be greyed out.

Comment: Aha! My original input was the single word, illegal. Tried again just now and there's a delay but it did work.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. It won't let you submit until you've typed in 15 characters or one of the other reasons. Therefore, there's no reason to show a button you can't click, anyway.

Comment: Actually, there's one reason: the SO Team thinks it's funny when you click over and over on the deactivated button.

Comment: Disagree. The button *should* be there for reasons of discoverability. There's no reason a user *should* know they have to type in 15 characters; hence, a confusing experience. A grayed out button gives the user the opportunity to mouse-over or attempt to push the disabled button and get a tip "You have to type in 15 characters." Joel and Jeff discuss this in Podcast 14 but they don't do it much here. Joel advocates this in his article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html . Controversial, but I agree with him if it is done right.